# Autowiring Custom DBAL connection in Symfony 3.3

Tags: symfony

Hello friends of symfony. I'm building a project that needs 2 connections to database. And it works nice, but if I want to get/use the second (called customer) connection by dependency injection instead of $this->container->get('doctrine.dbal.customer_connection'); it takes the default connection. I'm trying to use the dependency injection because is the new way to work with symfony and I understand that the other way will be deprecated in news versions of Symfony, so I'm updating my code to the new way to code.

I have this configuration that works nice.

```
config.yml
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver: pdo_mysql
                host: '%database_host%'
                port: '%database_port%'
                dbname: '%database_name%'
                user: '%database_user%'
                password: '%database_password%'
                charset: UTF8
            customer:
                driver: oci8
                host: '%database_host2%'
                port: '%database_port2%'
                dbname: '%database_name2%'
                user: '%database_user2%'
                password: '%database_password2%'
                charset: UTF8
```

So, if I use this next code inside a controller it returns what it's suppose to return, the customer connection.

```
$connection = $this->container->get('doctrine.dbal.customer_connection');
```

At the moment works good and I can get the customer connection.
So now, what I thought is create a service for this case called "QueriesCustomer", update the services.yml and finally update the parameters from the controller that I want to use with the services "QueriesCustomer" as a dependency injection ready to use in the controller.

```
<?php
#AppBundle/Service/QueriesOracle.php

namespace AppBundle\Service;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;

class QueriesOracle
{
    /**
     * @var Connection
    */
    private $oracleDB;


    /**
     * QueriesOracle constructor.
     * @param Connection $oracleDB
    */
    public function __construct(Connection $oracleDB)
    {
        $this->oracleDB = $oracleDB;
    }
}
```

and

```
services.yml
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false
    AppBundle\Services\QueriesOracle:
        class: AppBundle\Service\QueriesOracle
        arguments:
          - '@doctrine.dbal.customer_connection'
```

and finally the controller

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Service\QueriesOracle;
...

class AduanasController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @Route("/{_locale}/xxx")
     * @param Request $request
     * @param QueriesOracle $queriesOracle
     */
    public function nameOfFunctionAction(Request $request, QueriesOracle $queriesOracle)
    {
        dump($queriesOracle);die;
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this "problem"? I would like to use by dependency injection both connections without problems.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Detected the problem.... Was in service.yml     AppBundle\Service"s (needs to be deleted...)"\QueriesOracle:
        class: AppBundle\Service\QueriesOracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Detected the problem.... Was in service.yml AppBundle\Service"s (needs to be deleted...)"\QueriesOracle: class: AppBundle\Service\QueriesOracle